# Get unique values in a range where each value depends on the other cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Here is an example table columns A,B,C
where A - post time, B - name of a team, D - chosen date

```
10.08.2014 10:21:22, Name1, 25Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:23, Name1, 25Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:24, Name2, 28Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:25, Name2, 28Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:26, Name1, 28Mar
```

I want to get from the data above the following:

```
10.08.2014 10:21:22, Name1, 25Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:24, Name2, 28Mar
10.08.2014 10:21:26, Name1, 28Mar
```

Thus I want to select uique records by 2 columns: name(B) and date(C), however from the non-unique values based on B and C column, choose the one with the earliest time (column A).

How I can achive that in google spreadshits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in row 2, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(B2:B&C2:C), {B2:B&C2:C,A2:C}, {2,3,4}, 0))
```

and see if that works.
Note: depending on your locale the formula may need to be changed to:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(B2:B&C2:C); {B2:B&C2:C\A2:C}; {2\3\4}; 0))
```

and.. in case the data in col A is not sorted already...

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(B2:B&C2:C), sort({B2:B&C2:C,A2:C},2,1), {2,3,4}, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, more than I look. 2nd variant throws an erros, and date_time in column A should be already sorted as it is time response from google form

Comment: It's not possible that the first AND the second will work, because it depends on your locale. Some locales use commas as argument separators (e.g. U.S.), others use semi-colons (e.g. a lot of european countries). But glad to hear It worked.. :-)

Comment: I haven't noticed the difference of that comma =)